# R – Can't seem to reorganize a data set using pivot_longer

Tags: r, data-structures, pivot, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

| Sex | Controlled | Uncontrolled | SE_Controlled | SE_Uncontrolled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Male | a | c | e | g |
| Woman | b | d | f | h |

However, I find this layout unhelpful and I would like to have the following structure:

| Sex | Control | prop | SE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Male | Controlled | a | e |
| Woman | Controlled | b | f |
| Male | Uncontrolled | c | g |
| Woman | Uncontrolled | d | h |

I've tried using pivot_longer() but can't seem to find a correct solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ramirez, can you describe the new `prop` column? It looks like it contains the data formerly in `Controlled` and `Uncontrolled`, but then you seem also to include that data in the new `Control` column.

Comment: @RkeithL The values a, b, c, d are proportions of individuals with controlled or uncontrolled hypertension. That's the reason I would like a different column with these estimations and another one with control status.

Comment: In that case, can you add a bit of data to your query? I think that'll make it easier to help. Thanks!

Comment: what @RKeithL said, and also, it's very difficult to debug your function when you don't actually show the code for the function itself

Comment: ```df %>% rename_with(~gsub("^([^SE_])", "prop_\\1", .)) %>%  pivot_longer(-Sex, names_pattern = "(.*)(_Controlled|_Uncontrolled)$", names_to = c(".value", "Control"))```

Comment: @M-- you can just use `names_sep`, no need for a complex regex, see my answer

Comment: @Mark I usually post a comment similar to the dupe target answer to make sure everyone understands why this is a dupe. P.s. those are not complex patterns :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way of doing this is to:

1. Add a "temp" prefix to the columns we want to be a part of the "temp" column in the output, then
2. Pivot longer, using the first part of the column name as the name of the column we want the value to go into, and the second part as the value of the type column (the names_to syntax is a bit hard to read, but I hope that explanation makes sense).

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  rename_with(~ paste0("temp_", .x), .cols = c(Controlled, Uncontrolled)) |>
  pivot_longer(-Sex, names_to = c(".value", "type"), names_sep = "_")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  Sex   type         temp  SE   
  <chr> <chr>        <chr> <chr>
1 Male  Controlled   a     e    
2 Male  Uncontrolled c     g    
3 Woman Controlled   b     f    
4 Woman Uncontrolled d     h
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text="
Sex     Controlled  Uncontrolled    SE_Controlled   SE_Uncontrolled
Male    a   c   e   g
Woman   b   d   f   h", head = TRUE)
```